# Added library AAPT: error: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Why is the error due to the library?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:orientation="vertical">


<kr.docs.smartad.SmartAdBanner
    android:id="@+id/smartAdBanner"
    app:adv_AdOrder="Random"
    app:adv_BannerSize="Auto"
    app:adv_GoogleID="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:adv_IsAutoStart="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    iosched:adv_AdOrder="Random"
    iosched:adv_BannerSize="Rectangle" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_cat_title"
    android:text="@string/collections"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/category_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
AAPT: error: unbound prefix.

AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
AAPT: error: unbound prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `iosched:` prefix to `app:`

Comment: Please provide the stack trace